# Does cudaSetDevice Need to Be Called Prior to Kernel Launch with Stream?

Tags: cuda

I'm running the same CUDA kernel on multiple GPUs and intend to do so simultaneously using streams.  Does `cudaSetDevice` need to be called prior to launching the kernels with a unique stream id?  If not, great, but if so I think I'll need to somehow globally synchronize the calls to `cudaSetDevice`.

Note that I am creating the streams with a synchronized call to `cudaSetDevice` so the streams are guaranteed to be associated with that particular GPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  `cudaStream`s that you create are *specific to the device that was in effect when you created the stream*.

From the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multi-device-system):

> A kernel launch will fail if it is issued to a stream that is not associated to the current device ...

Comment: +1 but ouch - doesn't that kind of defeat (some of) the utility of streams since you've gotta synchronize cudaSetDevice and mykernel<<<>>> from the launching threads?

Comment: can't you just do `cudaSetDevice` before launching the kernel?  I don't see what the problem is.  I've not heard this objection before.

Comment: Yes and no - If everything is launched from the same thread - no problem.  If multiple threads are launching then you risk the following: (thread1) cudaSetDevice(1)->schedule out to thread2->cudaSetDevice(2)->schedule back to thread1->mykernel<<<>>> if the set-launch block is not synchronized.

Comment: the cuda device in use is a per-thread concept.  There is no possibility for thread B to modify the cuda device in use by thread A.  Note [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb): "Sets device as the current device **for the calling host thread.**"

Comment: To strengthen the prior comment by @RobertCrovella, a frequently used approach to multi-GPU is to have 1-to-1 correspondence between threads and GPUs. Then each of those threads calls `cudaSetDevice` once in the beginning, and never calls it again. All subsequent CUDA API calls in this thread will be issued to the corresponding GPU. Also note that you do not need to explicitly create and manage streams as long as you only need one stream per GPU. Default stream would do.

Comment: The opposite approach is to control multiple GPUs from one thread - and in this case you do need to call `cudaSetDevice` when the thread transitions from issuing commands to one GPU to issuing commands to another GPU. Even in this case you can use default streams (which are per-GPU) and so will never need to create streams explicitly unless you need multiple streams per one GPU.